# How to prevent crash when key in char while it request for int in c programme

Tags: c

```
printf("\t\t\tOption \n");
    printf("\t\t\t1 - Purchase a interplanet ticket \n");
    printf("\t\t\t2 - Back \n");
    printf("Please select the option \n\n>>");
    scanf_s("%d", &option_1);
```

How to prevent my program from crash when I key in letter instead of number?

Comment: I think `scanf_s` requires another parameter, why not use normal `scanf()` instead.

Comment: @Haris  It will require but with specifiers `%c, %s and %[` not with `%d` .

Answer (score 1):

The crash happens after the `scanf_s()` call, you must check the return value of `scanf()` in order to ensure that the `option_1` variable was intiailized.

I don't know how to use the `scanf_s()` function and I wouldn't use it because it's not standard, but with the `scanf()` function you can do this

```
int option_1;
if (scanf("%d", &option_1) != 1)
{
    // Reading option_1 would mean be a problem here
    // because it's not initialized, so doing that would be
    // undefined behavior.
    doSomething_But_DoNot_Try_To_Read_option_1();
}
else
{
    // Here it's ok
    switch (option_1)
    {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
         .
         .
         .
    case n:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

The `scanf()` function returns the number of matched parameters, so you can check for that to avoid problems.

Another approach is to explicitly initialize `option_1` before `scanf()`, you can set it to an invalid value (*a value that you are not going to handle as an option, like `-1` for example*). This way the `option_1` will be initialized and reading it would no longer cause *Undefined Behavior*, but checking the return value of `scanf()` allows the program to validate user input, altough recovering from it is really difficult, and I would recommend `fgets()` + `strtol()` instead, the same functionality but a lot easier to recover from bad input.

Comment: I recommend *explicitly initializing* variables, e.g. coding `int option_1= -1;`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I thought of that, but then I realized that the value of the answer is to learn how to check for `scanf()`'s return value. Although it would be better to explain that too.